# WP_Query arguments dropped by "posts_where" filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, categories

```
<?php
        $cat = get_query_var('cat');
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
            // posts for March 1 to March 15, 2010
            $where .= " AND post_date >= '2010-03-01' AND post_date < '2010-03-16'";
            return $where;
        }
        $args = array(
            'cat' => 4,
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where');
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
        if ($my_query->have_posts()):
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

                get_template_part('single', 'bandi');

            endwhile;
        endif; ?>
```

Here is my code.
Im trying to display posts from specific category, within date range.
Without filter query work fine, return posts from provided category. Adding filter makes query return posts within date range, but remove category id, and query return posts from whole site.
Any help?
Thanks